# Mysql Concatenation

Tags: mysql, concatenation

How to do concatenation in mysql? I have table `logs` in which there is a field `logs_status` which consists of a value in a format like `log_name`+OK  for example ,`some_logeOK`, so i need to join `log_name` with ok and select all

```
WHERE `logs_status` = `log_name`+OK
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you should use **[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**

```
WHERE `logs_status` = CONCAT(`log_name`, 'OK')
```